# How do I prevent the creation of new users by unauthenticated users in LoopBack 2.0?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

How do I prevent the creation of new users by unauthenticated users in LoopBack 2.0?

I've just made a quick test on a brand new LoopBack install and it looks like any anonymous user can create new users by simply sending a POST request to `/api/users`.

Data:

```
{"email": "test@test.com", "password": "hello123"}
```

Response Code: 200

Response Body:

```
{
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "id": 2
}
```

Apart from this issue, are there any other security issues similar to this that I should take care of?

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem like a security issue to me. This is the expected behavior. You can find default ACLs for User model here: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/User#user
If you want to restrict access to this method, you'll need to apply custom ACLs and, for example, create ADMIN role and limit certain operations to users who have this role. Some related loopback issues:

- [How to customize default ACLs](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/104)
- [Customize ACLs in model-config](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/669)

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating an API with restricted access I agree this could be an issue. I'm sure that there are ways to get around this, such as creating restricted access roles for your sensitive data, but it would be nice to have an easy way to change the default User model ACLs.